# Adding a custom Field similar to Assignee Field In Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to add a Custom field with list format where some users name will be included.And this field should be exactly similar like assignee field what we already have in Redmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the *Users* field type? It's under Administration | Custom Fields | New custom field.